# jekyll post name misunderstanding

Tags: jekyll

I'm new to jekyll blog

I have this post name which shows on the blog: 2023-01-28-design test.md

```
---
title: "design test"
last_modified_at: 2023-01-28
categories:
  - Blog
tags:
  - design
  - color
classes: wide

# Introduction
---
```

And this post name does not show on the blog: 2023-02-01-how-to-use-color.md
Also tried this file name: 2023-02-01-how to use color.md

```
---
title: "how to use color"
last_modified_at: 2023-02-01
categories:
  - Blog
tags:
  - design
  - color
classes: wide
---

# Introduction
```

I would really appreciate some comments on that since I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Jekyll doesn't recognize post name with future dates as a valid post.

I added the future date randomly for testing purposes but looks like I lost myself in the debugging process.